# How to silent the multi comments in shell-scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to comment multi lines. But unlike as `#[single line comment]`, when commented using `[:' ']`, it shows the commented list on the window as below,

```
 ./simple2.sh
./simple2.sh: line 7: :
Comment1
Comment2
Comment3
Comment4
: command not found
```

My code

```
#! /bin/bash
:'
Comment1
Comment2
Comment3
Comment4
'
```

How to silent the multi comments in shell-scripting?

Comment: can you provide the shell script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
: '
text
text
...
'
```

So you missed a space after `:`. Instead of

```
:'
```

you need

```
: '
 ^
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"

: '
bla
bla
bla
'

echo "bye"

$ ./a.sh
hello
bye
```

See more info in [Shell Script Put Multiple Line Comment](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-comment-out-multiple-line-code/).

Answer (score 3):

There is two way to putting multiple line comments in the bash script. Check the below script for both. You are getting error because of missing space between : and quotes as pointed by Fedorqui

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to show how to put multiple line comments in the bash shell script
# Check there are 2 ways to do it..
echo "Before Comments"
<<COMMENT1
    your comment 1
    comment 2
COMMENT1
echo "After Comments"

# there is another way
echo "Before Comments Part2"
# check there is space between : and ' quotes on below line
: '
This is a test comment
Another comment
'
echo "After Comments Part2"
# rest of script
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` does not have multi-line comments; you should check your text editor for a way to quickly prefix a selected group of lines with `#` to properly comment them.

If you get in the habit of using hackish work-arounds like `: '...'`, someday you'll try to "comment" out code like

```
x='foo bar'
```

or accidentally nest such a comment.

```
: '
some-command
: '
A comment
'
'
```

Get into the habit of commenting your code *correctly*:

```
# This is a multi-line comment
# in bash. It's simply a set of adjacent
# single-line comments.
```